# Django: Reverse lookup of optional foreignkey-entry and inclusion in dataset

Tags: python, django, templates, foreign-keys

I would like to compose list of database entries, and corresponding (but not necessarily existing) related entries in another table.

The concrete context is a list of events, in which the user should be able to see, whether he already stated his participation (thus has an entry in the database which should be displayed) or not (which would give him a link to a participation form)

My models (minimal):

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    #...

class Event_Participation(models.Model):
    EVENT_PARTICIPATION_CHOICES = [
        ("Y", "Yes"),
        ("N", "No"),
         # few other options
    ]
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participation = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= EVENT_PARTICIPATION_CHOICES)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=10) #originally another foreign key
```

Ideally, I'm searching for one expression like *Event.appendIfExists(Event_Participation)*...

For template rendering, I was able to query the data, but this doesn't seem elegant and I don't know, how to merge the information inside the template:

```
def event_list(request):
    e_all = Event.objects.all() #normally filtered
    part_list = {}
    for e in e_all:
        if e.event_participation_set.get(user_id = request.user.id) :
            p = e.event_participation_set.get(user_id = request.user.id).participation
        else:
            p = "X"
        part_list[e.id]= p
        context = {"part_list":part_list,"full_event_list":e_all}
        return render(request, "event_list.html", context)
```

An index-based variable in the template did not work for *part_list*, and I was not able to extend the queries in a way, which allowed me to use only one dict like this:

```
{% for event in full_event_list %}
        <li> {{ event.title }}
           {# Participation: {% if event.participation %} {{ event.participation }} {% else %} LINK {%endif%}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Since this seems like a very common application, I am probably missing something very obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` methods to perform database joins and reduce the number of queries.

We want `Event` objects along with their related `Event_Participation` objects for the current user.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def event_list(request):
    participations = Event_Participation.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    events = Event.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('event_participation_set', queryset=participations, to_attr='user_participations')
    )

    return render(request, "event_list.html", {'events': events})
```

then in our template we can access the related `Event_Participation` objects for each `event`

```
{% for event in events %}
    <li>
        {{ event.title }}
        {% for participation in event.user_participations %}
            Participation: {{ participation.participation }}
        {% empty %}
            LINK
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```